# How to automatically populate classes with random data c#?

Tags: c#

At the moment I'm manually typing the values in when i'm instantiating the class.
I was wondering is there a library that can automate this process in c#?

I need to assert the `List<Employee> Company.GetEmployees();` return exactly matches.

I need to return a List populated with 100 values.

```
class Employee
{
   public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
   public DateTime EndDate{get; set;}
   public decimal Salary {get; set;}

};
```

Some of the tests that i need to generate data for have nested classes, sometimes more than 5 classes.
manually generating data is error prone and time consuming. How would you solve the issue?

Comment: The Bogus library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few interesting libraries that can do this stuff.

- [Nbuilder](https://github.com/nbuilder/nbuilder)
- [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)
- [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus)

There are more, but you can also easily create your own wrapper.